# Directus Filtering multiple fields

Tags: filter, directus

I'm trying to filter Directus CMS data set through URL parameters.
This is a sample data set. I can successfully filter data set by single parameter.

```json
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id": "1",
         "status": "published",
         "category": "Novel",
         "section": "Kids"
      },
      {
         "id": "2",
         "status": "published",
         "category": "Novel",
         "section": "Adults"
      }
   ]
}
```

> /items/books?filter[category][_eq]=Novel

gives me exactly what I expected which is 1 & 2 data records.
But I need to filter both "category" &  "section" fields

```
/items/books?filter[category][_eq]=Novel&filter[section][_eq]=Adults
```

For above I receive an empty data set.
Why is this getting failed ? Where do I need to fix? Appreciate your support in advance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
/items/books?filter={"_or":[{"category":{"_eq": "Novel"}},{"section":{"_eq":"Adults"}}]}
```

An expanded version of the filter:

```json
"_or": [
    {
        "category": {
            "_eq": "Novel"
        }
    },
    {
        "section": {
            "_eq": "Adults"
        }
    }
]
```

Visit the [official docs](https://docs.directus.io/reference/filter-rules.html#logical-operators) to read more about filtering rules and logical operators.